# Giving a class it parameters from other classes-Python

Tags: python

I have a class sendmail and I am trying to call it in other classes.The `argument` will determine which email to send. The `argument` in the sendmail class will send mail according to parameters given to it from other classes where it is being called.However,when executing it, I get error message saying `argument` not defined.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
class sendmail(argument):

  TO = 'yourmail@gmail.com'
  if argument=='PIR':
    SUBJECT = 'PIR'
    TEXT = 'Motion is detected'

  gmail_sender = 'mymail@gmail.com'
  gmail_passwd = 'mypwd'

  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  server.ehlo()
  server.starttls()
  server.ehlo
  server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

  BODY = '\r\n'.join([
       'TO: %s' % TO,
       'From: %s' % gmail_sender ,
       'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT ,
       '',
       TEXT
       ])
  try:
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
    print 'email sent'
  except:
    print 'error'

  server.quit()
```

Comment: You're trying to use a class like a function. Don't do that. Read a tutorial on classes (maybe the [official Python tutorial chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)).

Comment: `argument` is supposed to be a class to inherit from

Comment: This looks like you meant to create a function, not a class

Comment: Meanwhile, if you want people to debug your code, you need to provide a [mcve]. We can tell you what's wrong with this code, but we can't tell you how to write it properly if we don't know exactly what "parameters given to it from other classes" means, or how you're trying to use this.

Comment: @abarnert  I tried,but I keep getting confused with _init_ and self.

Comment: You almost certainly just want a function, not a class.

Comment: @Elfinforest If you can't understand what classes are for and how they're used, just don't use one. You definitely don't need a class for this problem. When you later run into a problem where you _do_ need a class, all the abstract nonsense in the tutorial will match up with real things in your real problem, so it'll be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a static function.

```
import smtplib
class MailUtils:
    @staticmethod    
    def sendmail(argument):

          TO = 'yourmail@gmail.com'
          if argument=='PIR':
            SUBJECT = 'PIR'
            TEXT = 'Motion is detected'

          gmail_sender = 'mymail@gmail.com'
          gmail_passwd = 'mypwd'

          server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
          server.ehlo()
          server.starttls()
          server.ehlo
          server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

          BODY = '\r\n'.join([
               'TO: %s' % TO,
               'From: %s' % gmail_sender ,
               'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT ,
               '',
               TEXT
               ])
          try:
            server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
            print 'email sent'
          except:
            print 'error'

          server.quit()
```

You would use it by doing this:

```
import MailUtils
MailUtils.sendmail(argument)
```

*Note: As mentioned in the comments below, this approach works best if the class contains multiple related functions, not just a single one.*

Comment: A class should not be used this way. The class only contains a static method and is thus totally useless. Only use a function.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon He said in his question that he wanted to use it in other classes (plural), unless you want to rewrite the function every time, a static function is the most organized.

Comment: Then it should be a function, and other classes will call a function, not a static method. The only real point of static methods is grouping a bunch of functions in a same namespace, which is not the case here.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon The way I've understood it is that it's a way of putting functions into a class because it belongs there logically, but it doesn't need access to the class itself. So, in this case, if you have a "Mail" class (or a "MailUtils" class), the sendmail static method belongs there, just for the sake of making the program more readable. I do understand that they are not needed most of the time, but I still like how it organizes things. (I'm of course open to being wrong, just trying to understand what you mean). :)

Comment: A MailUtils class with other static methods would make sense. A Mail class with a single one, not so much. I suggest you add that as a note/warning.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Yeah, I agree, this answer was mostly just to illustrate that static functions were a possible answer to the question. (I added the note)

Comment: With the note added, I think this is now a fair answer. Thanks for the update!

Comment: @ThomasS. That makes sense.